# How can I ignore a TCP PSH bit in Windows 7?

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, boost, tcp

I have a C++ program that uses Boost ASIO to communicate with a network device over a TCP socket. The program is working fine on Linux, but with Windows 7 I'm finding that the communication is not working very well. After some experimentation, I found that there's a 0.5-second delay between command and response when communicating with the device using the ASIO example telnet program, even though the response shows up in Wireshark much more quickly.

I gather that the problem is that the network device is not setting the PSH flag after it completes a chunk of data. See: http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-tcp-push-flag.html.

I need to somehow set up my app so that it receives data from the TCP socket regardless of whether a packet has arrived with the PSH bit set. I know this must be possible because PuTTY can communicate with my device normally. I'd rather not use a registry key to get the effect, because I want to change the behavior only for this one socket, not the entire system.

What do I need to do to get Windows to ignore the PSH flag for this connection?

Comment: The PSH flag is basically meaningless. It is often not set and almost universally ignored when set. The original concept is out of kilter with the BSD Sockets API.

Comment: I think you may have _gathered_ a [red herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring). Care to share a SSCCE?

Comment: It seems to require a TCP stack that doesn't set the PSH bit, but given that, all you need is a Windows 7 machine running the Boost.ASIO telnet client example: http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/att-40895/telnet.cpp.

Comment: Have you tried changing the `IgnorePushBitOnReceives` registry setting mentioned in the article to see if it actually improves things for you?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that changing the registry to set `IgnorePushBitOnReceives` solves the problem.

Comment: Are you sure the delay is on the receiving side ? Have you turn off the nagle algorithm, by setting the TCP_NODELAY socket option (setsockopt()) ? Have you debugged the program and verified it's not something simple as output buffering by e.g. cout

Comment: I don't believe the article you linked to in your question is correct. It seems to be implying that TCP waits for a segment with the PSH bit set before transferring any data to the application. This is simply untrue. See *man recv().* It is specified to block until at least one byte has been transferred, and there are thousands of questions here that are motivated by not understanding that and wondering hwy they get incomplete messages. Those questions wouldn't exist if the behaviour was as described in the article.

Comment: As I said above, the original PSH concept doesn't play with the actual Opckets API that was shipped: it was to provide some kind of interrupting behaviour to applications. That's not what happened.

Comment: @EJP `man recv` doesn't define the behaviour on Windows, which has always had certain eccentricities in its TCP stack. And the RFC still mentions waiting for PSH on receive. (RFC793 p48)

Answer (score 1):

You could try specifying the `MSG_PUSH_IMMEDIATE` flag on the receiving side (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741688(v=vs.85).aspx).